# Why does ChatGPT API in Python respond incorrectly on basic queries?

Tags: openai-api, chatgpt-api

I'm currently using chatgpt api for a more complex task but for the time given the query is quite simple, yet It responds incorrectly (web version does not have this problem). The code looks like this:

```py
import openai
openai.api_key = 'REDACTED'
#messages = [{"role":"system", "content": "Act as if you're making a catalog for an online store. I will give you a list of products, split them into categories and I want you to eliminate less important categories. Do not add any descriptions, just tell me the remaining products and categories. The output should be in the following format: each category followed by the products that fit in it. After that, show the eliminated categories and products in the same format."}]
messages = [{"role":"system", "content": "You are making a catalog for an online store. In the next prompt, I will give you a list of items, I want you to split them into categories. They should be output in the following format: Each category followed by the items that belong in it."}]
content = input('User: The items are: ')
messages.append({"role":"user", "content": content})

completion = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
    model = "gpt-3.5-turbo",
    messages = messages,
    temperature = 0.7
)
response = completion.choices[0].message.content
print(f'CHATGPT:{response}')
messages.append({"role": "assistant", "content": response})
```

The response looks like this:

User: The items are: ['Banquette Seating' 'Restaurant Chairs' 'Design Furniture'
'Restaurant Upholstery' 'Restaurants And Bars' 'Bar Seating'
'Design & Manufacturing' 'Dining Chair' 'Bistro Seating'
'Repair And Restoration' 'Padded Wall Dining Chairs' 'Office Chair']
CHATGPT:Category: Banquette Seating

- Banquette Seating

Category: Restaurant Chairs

- Restaurant Chairs

Category: Design Furniture

- Design Furniture

I've noticed that whenever I give a query that requires a list, it only takes the first 3 elements into consideration. I've also tried with a while true loop to ask recurrent prompts but instead the output was User: ChatGPT: (6 items), User: ChatGPT: (9 items), etc.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Solved. I had long inputs copy-pasted from multiple rows and the input() only took the first line.